# Rails App crashes when deployed to Heroku, not sure what to make of the logs, started when 1.9.1->1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, crash, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Ok, I give up and need your help. My Rails app crashes on Heroku and used to work before 1.9.3. I've gone through all the changes for 1.9.3, even creating a new app, but it still always crashes. Works fine locally. The following is in the heroku logs:

```
2013-01-09T03:00:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 52530
2013-01-09T03:01:04+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:689: warning: already initialized constant POP3Session
2013-01-09T03:01:04+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:702: warning: already initialized constant APOPSession
2013-01-09T03:01:04+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/smtp.rb:806: warning: already initialized constant SMTPSession
2013-01-09T03:01:04+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:687: warning: already initialized constant POP
2013-01-09T03:01:04+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:688: warning: already initialized constant POPSession
2013-01-09T03:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.8/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `parse_options'
2013-01-09T03:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:33:in `parse!' (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
2013-01-09T03:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.8/lib/rack/server.rb:180:in `options'
2013-01-09T03:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-01-09T03:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
2013-01-09T03:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2013-01-09T03:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:58:in `start'
2013-01-09T03:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-01-09T03:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
2013-01-09T03:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-01-09T03:01:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-01-09T03:01:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-01-09T03:01:11+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=xxxxxx.herokuapp.com fwd=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I've solved it. The clue in the logs was:

```
2013-01-09T03:01:08+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:33:in `parse!' (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
```

Which indicated that the thin webserver was unable to start with the arguments passed. Based on this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3,  I changed my procfile from:

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT
```

To this:

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV
```

And set the RACK_ENV to staging in my environment with this:

```
$ echo "RACK_ENV=development" >>.env
```

Now it works and on to other issues.